# Can i have the PDF revision history or revision number or value in the DITA PDF output?

Tags: xslt, dita, oxygenxml, dita-ot

I need to provide a way for the customers to know the PDF revision numbers or date. I need to have the revision value or timestamp or anything similar at the footnote of the PDF. I tried adding tags in the bookmeta, but they are not picked during the build. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would use for publishing DITA to PDF Oxygen's specific "DITA Map PDF - based on HTML5 & CSS" transformation scenario which uses CSS for customizing the PDF output, you can use CSS pagination techniques:
https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/24.1/ug-editor/topics/dcpp_headers_and_footers.html#ariaid-title7

If the DITA Map looks like this:

```
 <map>
   <title>Growing Flowers</title>
   <topicmeta>
     <critdates>
       <revised modified="2022-06-03"/>
     </critdates>
```

define for example a stringset with a certain name and use the stringset in the header for example:

```
 *[class ~= "topic/revised"] {
   string-set: hdrstr attr(modified);
  }
  @page {  
   @top-left-corner {
     content: string(hdrstr);
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, but you won't get it by default using the DITA Open Toolkit (which I assume that you are using). You'll need to create a customized PDF plug-in that will generate footers that pick up information from where ever it is in the DITA source.

The DITA-OT documentation and Leigh White's book "DITA For Print" will probably help you learn to create a customized plug-in. Or modify one, if you are working with a customized PDF plug-in to begin with.

You might want to post about this on the dita-users list. You can join the dita-users list at https://dita-users.groups.io/g/main ; be sure to scroll down to the bottom of the page

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I am trying to add a custom setting for the footers. Let me see. Will go through the book as well :)